# Задержка реакции apache2

Tags: apache, php, linux

С начала расскажу что да как. Виртуальная машина на VirtualBox. На ней установлено

**Система:** Linux ocsinventory-ng 2.6.32-38-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 4 11:13:04 UTC 2012 i686 GNU/Linux

Apache/2.2.14

PHP 5.3.2(built: Dec 13 2011 18:45:32)

Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies

MySQL 5.1.41

Стоит на apache - OCS Inventory NG и GLPI 0.80.61.

В общем проблема в том что при работе в GLPI большое время генерации страницы. Как мне кажется это из за обращений к БД. Но собственно обращений не так уж и много, и машина должна справятся. Посмотрел на загрузку ЦП - оказалось ЦП практически не что не грузит. Только много процессов таких как:

```
www-data  9769  0.1  2.8  54800 19872 ?        S    23:22   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9770  0.0  2.8  54524 19920 ?        S    23:22   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9771  0.1  3.1  56708 21996 ?        S    23:22   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9772  0.1  3.0  56176 21664 ?        S    23:22   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9773  0.1  3.0  56204 21684 ?        S    23:22   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9786  0.2  2.7  54260 19816 ?        S    23:26   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9787  0.1  3.0  56176 21592 ?        S    23:26   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9788  0.1  3.0  56456 21748 ?        S    23:26   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9818  0.1  3.0  56424 21900 ?        S    23:28   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

10 процессов, потребляющих наибольшее количество памяти:

```
Warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See http://procps.sf.net/faq.html
mysql      673  0.2  4.1 153508 29096 ?        Ssl  14:25   1:14 /usr/sbin/mysqld
www-data  9818  0.1  3.1  56680 22288 ?        S    23:28   0:02  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9788  0.1  3.1  56712 22420 ?        S    23:26   0:02  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9787  0.1  3.2  56456 23140 ?        S    23:26   0:02  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9773  0.1  3.1  56204 22184 ?        S    23:22   0:02  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9772  0.1  3.0  56176 21820 ?        S    23:22   0:03  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9771  0.0  3.1  56708 22080 ?        S    23:22   0:01  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9786  0.1  2.8  54260 20316 ?        S    23:26   0:03  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9770  0.1  2.8  54524 20172 ?        S    23:22   0:02  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9769  0.1  2.9  54800 20676 ?        S    23:22   0:02  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

10 процессов, потребляющих наибольший ресурс процессора:

```
Warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See http://procps.sf.net/faq.html
www-data  9818  0.1  3.1  56680 22288 ?        S    23:28   0:02  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Использование памяти:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           692        460        231          0         44        266
-/+ buffers/cache:        149        542
Swap:         1619          0       1619
```

средняя загрузка процессора, активность дисков:

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           1,12    0,00    2,65    0,21    0,00   96,02

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda               0,77        15,01        20,48     517586     706184
```

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте опцию в `httpd.conf`

```
ServerType standalone|inetd
```

Если у вас `inetd` смените на `standalone`. Как пишут [здесь](http://macosx.com/forums/design-media/32528-httpd-servertype-standalone-vs-inetd-mode.html):

> You really don't want to run it from
> inetd because you will have to startup
> a new apache process for every
> connection. And remember every image
> and such in a web page is a new
> connection. It is just a way to make
> your machine server fewer pages with a
> higher load

Т.е. на каждое соединение будет создаваться новый процесс.

Comment: А у меня httpd.conf пустой. Да и в apache2.conf  я такой строчки не нашел. Как я прочитал http://www.apache.ru/docs/fishki.html#ServerType так же не нашел таких опций... Где мне найти эти опции? И как мне это поможет?
Да кстати ещё прочитал одну статью, может это относится ко мне http://phpsuxx.blogspot.com/2008/01/apache2-prefork-vs-worker.html

Comment: Да, это одна из возможностей.

Comment: АТАк а где мне опцию ServerType искать?

Comment: Не пробовали прописать его в `httpd.conf`?

Comment: Допустим я поставлю опцию ServerType inetd, то как будет себя вести apache2 ? Как будет вести себя apache?

Comment: Наоборот, он сейчас себя ведет как `inetd`. А потом будет один процесс, но много потоков. На создание потока уходит меньше времени, чем на создание процесса. Кроме того, можно настроить, сколько клиентов может обслуживать один поток и т.п.